# How to dynamically call an operator in Elixir

Tags: function, dynamic, macros, operator-keyword, elixir

I'm working my way through Dave's upcoming book on Elixir, and in one exercise I would like to dynamically construct a function reference to `Kernel.+/2`, `Kernel.-/2` etc, based on the contents of one character of a string, `'+'`, `'-'` and so on.

Based on another SO question I expected to be able to call `apply/3` passing Kernel, :+ and the two numbers like this:

```
apply(Kernel, :+, [5, 7])
```

This doesn't work because (if I understand right) `Kernel.+/2` is a macro, not a function.  I looked up the source code, and `+` is defined in terms of `__op__`, and I can call it from `iex`:

```
__op__(:+, 5, 7)
```

This works until I put the :+ into a variable:

```
iex(17)> h = list_to_atom('+')
:+
iex(18)> __op__(h, 5, 7)
** (CompileError) iex:18: undefined function __op__/3
    src/elixir.erl:151: :elixir.quoted_to_erl/3
    src/elixir.erl:134: :elixir.eval_forms/4
```

And I'm guessing there's no way to call `__op__` using `apply/3`.

Of course, the brute-force method gets the job done.

```
  defp _fn(?+), do: &Kernel.+/2
  defp _fn(?-), do: &Kernel.-/2
  defp _fn(?*), do: &Kernel.*/2
# defp _fn(?/), do: &Kernel.//2   # Nope, guess again
  defp _fn(?/), do: &div/2        # or &(&1 / &2) or ("#{div &1, &2} remainder #{rem &1, &2}")
```

But is there something more concise and dynamic?

---

José Valim nailed it with his answer below.  Here's the code in context:

```
  def calculate(str) do 
    {x, op, y} = _parse(str, {0, :op, 0})
    apply :erlang, list_to_atom(op), [x, y]
  end

  defp _parse([]     , acc      )                 , do: acc
  defp _parse([h | t], {a, b, c}) when h in ?0..?9, do: _parse(t, {a, b, c * 10 + h - ?0})
  defp _parse([h | t], {_, _, c}) when h in '+-*/', do: _parse(t, {c, [h], 0})
  defp _parse([_ | t], acc      )                 , do: _parse(t, acc)
```

Comment: (not too relevant to your question) my solution looks so different than yours! https://gist.github.com/nielsbom/0d689e00d927cc057ad7c5595d7e8f06

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use the Erlang one:

```
apply :erlang, :+, [1,2]
```

We are aware this is confusing and we are studying ways to make it or more explicit or more transparent.

UPDATE: Since Elixir 1.0, you can dispatch directly to Kernel (`apply Kernel, :+, [1, 2]`) or even use the syntax the OP first attempted (`&Kernel.+/2`).

Comment: By the way, what would have been the proper incantation for the / macro, since &Kernel.//2 doesn't work?

Comment: This should do it: `&(Kernel./)/2` (or `&(&1 / &2)`)

Comment: If you have the operator as a single-quoted string, use List.to_atom(operator) as the second argument to apply